# Android 2.3.3 Packages (what am I downloading?)

Tags: android

Hi can anyone tell me what all the other packages for android 2.3.3 in the SDK manager? The SDK platform, sample SDKs, and google APIs are always necessary in all SDKs. But what are the rest of the packages (Intel Atom, Real3D, Droid4, Motorola, etc.). Should I download them as well?

For what I can tell they look like compatibility packages for different phones or something. Does anyone know/want to share the full story on this, *specifically why 2.3.3 has so many packages and the rest of the SDKs don't*? All responses appreciated.

PS: I know this isn't a programming question and shouldn't be asked here, but a lot of people programming for Android go here, so I might as well ask it once.

Comment: I am assuming them to be emulator files, can you provide more info, where exactly are you downloading the files from? etc.,

Comment: They're apis for some phones, you shouldn't need the unless your targeting some of these phones

Comment: Great that saves a lot of time :). But I'm curious to know why 2.3.3 has all these phones and the rest of the SDKs don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** Mentioning those packages with like Real3D, Droid4, Motorola etc, are straight away pointing **to include the APIs that will expose the functionality provided by those Phones.**

**-**  Now as you mentioned that `SDK` version `2.3.3` has all these packages where others don't, well **its because these are targeted to the Devices which has** `SDK 2.3.3` version **installed and working on them**, You will see that `SDK version 3.2` has `XOOM2ME` and `XOOM2`, **which is not present in other packages, it because of same reason i mentioned above....**

Comment: I'm still very new to all of this. What functionality is being exposed? Are these phones unable to upgrade their OS? Isn't Android suppose to be device independent it seems strange to me that specific API's are needed for phones. What I'm still not understanding is specifically, why these API's are necessary at all...

Comment: @user1490379 First some phones like the one i have HTC explorer which is running 2.3.6 can't be upgraded to 4.0 cause it `lower RAM and less processor speed`. And when i said functionality being exposed, i mean... suppose i have MOTOROLA ATRIX 4G, which supports the Finger Print Scanning, i need to have `those APIs imported into my SDK, so i can program using those API for that functionality...`